# Google Play Security Issues?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, android-security

This is my first time submitting an app to the Google Play store, so I'm not very experienced with the process at all. After struggling for a bit to get it to build correctly, I was finally able to upload an app bundle and send it in for review. A few minutes later I got an email saying my app was "vulnerable to Intent Redirection" and recommended the following article for support: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555. The problem is I don't understand much of what the article is saying! As far as I know, I haven't messed with anything like this. I've only downloaded the base NDK and SDK stuff from Unity Hub, and I haven't changed any of the code in Android Studio at all. I asked Google for support, and they said:

> "We’ve identified that your app is using the AliPay SDK or library, which facilitates the transmission of phone number information without meeting the prominent disclosure guidelines. If necessary, you can consult your SDK provider(s) for further information or please upgrade AliPay SDK version to 15.5.5 or higher."

Please help! Is there an easy fix to this that I'm missing somehow? I don't even know what AliPay is, as I said I'm a total beginner here. In case it's useful info to have, I'm using Unity 2019.2.13f1 on a Macbook Pro running High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, do what the message says "upgrade AliPay SDK version to 15.5.5 or higher".

Just go to Android Studio and open your build.gradle file then update that lib version. It will be marked with a yellow line, that means that lib has an update. Focus on that line, then do Alt + Click then Enter, now sync and you've done. Upload the new apk.

Comment: I can't seem to find a build.gradle file... I tried using the search function but nothing came up. Or a manifest for that matter, I've seen both recommended to others but neither seems to exist in my project.